# split ndarray into chunks - whilst maintaining order

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to implement a function, which can split a 3 dimensional numpy array in to 8 pieces, whilst keeping the order intact. Essentially I need the splits to be:

```
G[:21, :18,:25]
G[21:, :18,:25]
G[21:, 18:,:25]
G[:21, 18:,:25]
G[:21, :18,25:]
G[21:, :18,25:]
G[21:, 18:,25:]
G[:21, 18:,25:]
```

Where the original size of this particular matrix would have been 42, 36, 50. How is it possible to generalise these 8 "slices" so I do not have to hardcode all of them? essentially move the `:`in every possible position.

Thanks!

Comment: In your example you split into two along each dimension, and all of your array dimensions are even. Are the dimensions of your array always divisible by the number of times you want to split along each dimension?

Comment: we can assume they will be.. if they are not they I will have to augment the matrices in some way anyway :)

Comment: were you looking for [np.split](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)?

Comment: This doesnt seem to let me split arrays within arrays (if that makes sense).

Comment: i think hardcoding here maybe the quick and dirty option :/

Comment: Your first column doesn't fit a normal binary alternation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply the 1d slice to successive (lists of) dimensions.

With a smaller 3d array

```
In [147]: X=np.arange(4**3).reshape(4,4,4)
```

A compound list comprehension produces a nested list.  Here I'm using the simplest double split

```
In [148]: S=[np.split(z,2,0) for y in np.split(X,2,2) for z in np.split(y,2,1)]
```

In this case, all sublists have the same size, so I can convert it to an array for convenient viewing:

```
In [149]: SA=np.array(S)

In [150]: SA.shape
Out[150]: (4, 2, 2, 2, 2)
```

There are your 8 subarrays, but grouped (4,2).

```
In [153]: SAA = SA.reshape(8,2,2,2)

In [154]: SAA[0]
Out[154]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[16, 17],
        [20, 21]]])

In [155]: SAA[1]
Out[155]: 
array([[[32, 33],
        [36, 37]],

       [[48, 49],
        [52, 53]]])
```

Is the order right?  I can change it by changing the axis in the 3 split operations.

Another approach is write your indexing expressions as tuples

```
In [156]: x,y,z = 2,2,2   # define the split points

In [157]: ind = [(slice(None,x), slice(None,y), slice(None,z)),     
                 (slice(x,None), slice(None,y), slice(None,z)),]  
                 # and so on

In [158]: S1=[X[i] for i in ind]

In [159]: S1[0]
Out[159]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[16, 17],
        [20, 21]]])

In [160]: S1[1]
Out[160]: 
array([[[32, 33],
        [36, 37]],

       [[48, 49],
        [52, 53]]])
```

Looks like the same order I got before.

That `ind` list of tuples can be produced with some sort of iteration and/or list comprehension.  Maybe even using `itertools.product` or `np.mgrid` to generate the permutations.

---

An `itertools.product` version could look something like

```
In [220]: def foo(i):
    return [(slice(None,x) if j else slice(x,None)) 
            for j,x in zip(i,[2,2,2])]

In [221]: SAA = np.array([X[foo(i)] for i in 
    itertools.product(range(2),range(2),range(2))])

In [222]: SAA[-1]
Out[222]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[16, 17],
        [20, 21]]])
```

`product` iterates the last value fastest, so the list is reversed (compared to your target).

To generate a particular order it may be easier to list the tuples explicitly, e.g.:

```
In [227]: [X[foo(i)] for i in [(1,1,1),(0,1,1),(0,0,1)]]
Out[227]: 
[array([[[ 0,  1],
         [ 4,  5]],

        [[16, 17],
         [20, 21]]]), array([[[32, 33],
         [36, 37]],

        [[48, 49],
         [52, 53]]]), array([[[40, 41],
         [44, 45]],

        [[56, 57],
         [60, 61]]])]
```

This highlights the fact that there are 2 distinct issues - generating the iteration pattern, and splitting the array based on this pattern.